# validate message with ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I use Validate.js to filter value of user key in

Now I make a ajax to check the value exists in DB

if the DB have the value than user 
can't save and return false and show error message

otherwise return true and use can change

now my error message will show before my ajax work finish

how to fix this problem?

```
 function onVlidate() {
    $.validator.addMethod("Saved", function (value, element, arg) {
        var data = $("#form1").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'checkSaved',
            data: data,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'Json',
            success: function (r) {
                console.log(r);
                if (r.IsSuccess) {              
                    return true;
                } else {
                    console.log(r.IsSuccess);
                    return false;
                }
            },
            error: function (r) {
                console.log(r.IsSuccess);
            }
        });
    }, "Error DB Change");
    $('#form1').validate({
        resetForm: function () { },
        rules: {
            'VerifyItem':{
                Saved: true
            }
        },
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Use `remote` instead of writing your own unproven method from scratch.

Comment: There is no such option called `resetForm` that you can put inside of the `.validate()` method.  Please review the documentation.

Comment: [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx)